# How to manage multiple thread with priority

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, android-listview

I have `listview` with `image and text` and for image i am using `urlimageviewhelper-1.0.4`. so my qustion is :

When first time i am loading first 30 item to listview then it shows all text and image is loading in asynchronous manner.

Now on `scroll` i am loading more 30 items to `listview`.

```
So It is bind to listview after first 30 images loading gets completed.
```

So i want to do like when i load more items to listview then it will be quickly bind to listview then later images loading `asynchronous` continue.

So how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue has several solutions. But I don't know your exact situation since for the moment your post seeks an idea without specific code. Let me start with Google's documentation about **loading bitmap images asynchronously** @ [Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html).

Your main issue is not with ListView. If you want to load 30 items at a time with a ListView, there are ways to do it OR simply not worry about it, at least not now.

Let us know of your progress and thoughts on this.